# How to recover github password without using 2FA credentials

Tags: github

I am using forgot password to change my GitHub password, but it's required 2FA credentials and I lost the 2FA app as well. So is there any I can change my password without using 2FA credentials?

Answer (score 1):

A list of possibilities is given in [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/recovering-your-account-if-you-lose-your-2fa-credentials) help page on GitHub.

To summarize, you can recover your account on your own, even after losing your 2FA app, if you (already) have:

1. A recovery code: you can download and safely keep a list of backup codes for situations like this.
2. A fallback number: a second phone number associated with your account.
3. A security key: you can have, for example, a physical USB stick as a security key.

Without this, there are two more methods provided, but will take longer and are not guaranteed to recover your account:

1. Using a verified device, SSH token, or personal access token: you can apply for account recovery by proving that you are logging in from a device you have used before, or using a SSH or personal access token that has been used before. The request will be then manually considered by GitHub support.
2. Using an account recovery token on Facebook (if you have set it previously): This also requires manual verification.

---

In general, to avoid such issues in the future, it would be advisable to download (and perhaps print a physical copy) of recovery codes for each service you use 2FA with, as that would be one of the easiest and fastest ways to recover your account.

Comment: I lost my Google auth app, As I have to hard reset my phone,  at the same time I installed a new Operating system in laptop, So I lost everything. I don't have recovery codes, don't have verified device, Only have access to email. 

What should  I do? Please help?